# Facebook Pixel flagging requests as malicious

Tags: facebook, web-frontend, facebook-pixel

Facebook Pixel is flagging requests to our domain as malicious, despite any of our systems explicitly adding these malicious query parameters.
Once a user does an event which requires authentication, the resulting URL is appended by something like
`/access?state=_removed_&code=_removed_&scope=_removed_&authuser=_removed_&prompt=_removed_&_filteredParams=_removed_`

`Note`: Specifically the **authuser** is added in this example, but not restricted to that element. Can be anything the malicious user is attempting to do.

This is restricted to a limited amount(<100) of user(s) making requests to this particular endpoint, however on Facebook side, it's flagged as malicious.

Is there a way of preventing this from happening?

- Attempted to detect if there is an additional query parameter being added on our frontend project, but none is detect, logged or flagged.
- Attempted to prevent the query parameter from reaching the server, which was successful, however the request to Facebook happens exclusively on the user's browser/client.

Comment: _"Can be anything the malicious user is attempting to do."_ - so we are actually talking about a case where you _have_ a user trying to do "malicious" things? Please clarify whether things are happening on _your_ site, that were not intended to happen in the first place - or whether the FB pixel reports _genuine_ actions as malicious. Also, does it _just_ say "malicious", and not nothing else? No further info _why_ they consider it malicious?

Comment: Correct, user(s) are attempting this. Does not happen from our site, but facebook pixel is flagging/reporting these seemingly "legitimate" requests from our side since the request "originates" from our site, however the additional query parameters in the request is not added from our code. We have done a thorough investigate to confirm that to be the case.

Comment: I don't know based on _what_ Facebook would decide, that these requests appear to be "malicious". Is there any more info on that?

Comment: _"Attempted to detect if there is an additional query parameter being added on our frontend project, but none is detect, logged or flagged"_ - if it is actually the pixel code doing the tracking (and they are not sending requests to the tracking endpoint directly), then I don't see how that could happen, unless they actually requested your site with those parameters in their browser.